# Python function with too many arguments with default values, how to make it cleaner?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following function signature, and it looks really ugly, what can I do to make it look cleaner ?

```
def contact(
  request, sender=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
  subj_tmpl='contato/subject.txt',msg_tmpl='contato/msg.html',
  template='contato/contato.html', success_template='contato/success.html',
  success_redir='/',append_message=None,):
```

Comment: You need to provide more context.  What is in your `urls.py`?  You need to explain the **reasons** why you have these parameters in the first place.  Depending on your function's **meaning**, they may be impossible to remove.  Just providing the `def` line does not provide enough context to make any recommendation at all.

Comment: just as a matter of style: you say `msg_tmpl`, but `success_template`. i consider arbitrary abbreviations a frequent and unhealthy programmer's condition. better to always fully spell out everything: `sender_email`, `subject_template`, `message_template`, `template` (what? which template? specify.), `success_template`, `on_success_redirect_to_url` (seriously. this is not physics where you have basics like length `s`, time `t`; this is very very very specific so sacrifice some more letters).

Comment: ah, one more thing. as of Python 2.7 (or 3 at least), you can use the new `def f( self, a, b, *, x, y = 42 )` syntax that forces users to supply argument names for everything following the star: `f( 1, 2, x = 3 )` is ok, but not `f( 1, 2, 3 )`. this is very good as it makes function calls with many arguments much clearer and more failsafe, as it is easy to supply a positional argument in the wrong position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i were you i think i will do it like this:

```
def contact(request, sender=None, append_message=None, context=None):

   if not sender:
       sender = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  # i hope that you can access settings here

   # The context arg is a dictionary where you can put all the others argument and 
   # you can use it like so :

   subj_tmpl = context.get('subj_tmpl', 'contato/subject.txt')
   # ....
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

My proposal is to drop parameters. Do you really need to be able to specify all the templates separately? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just specify the template folder, and then mandate that it has subject.txt, msg.html, etc in it?

If you just want to improve readability, reformat it to have one parameter per line:

```
def contact(
  request, 
  sender=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
  subj_tmpl='contato/subject.txt',
  msg_tmpl='contato/msg.html',
  template='contato/contato.html', 
  success_template='contato/success.html',
  success_redir='/',
  append_message=None,):
```

This will allow a reader to more quickly grasp what the parameter names are.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it as:

```
def contact( request, **kargs):
    try:
        sender = kwargs.pop ('sender')
    except KeyError:
        sender=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

    try:
        subj_tmpl = kwargs.pop ('subj_tmpl')
    except KeyError:
        subj_tmpl='contato/subject.txt'

    # ... 
    # and so on 
    # ...
```

Comment: But i will agree, the existing solution is not necessarily 'ugly'

Answer (score 0):

```
def contact(request, **kwargs):
    sender = kwargs.get('sender', settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)
    subj_template = kwargs.get('subj_template', 'contato/subject.txt')
    ..
```

With that said, I think your current solution is waaay better than using `**kwargs`.

Comment: Err, then why are you recommending this as "cleaner"?

Answer (score 0):

this does not seem so ugly to me: you have a function, you have enough parameters to modify the way the function behave, and you have sensible default values so that you don't need to specify all arguments at each function call.

there is the possibility to package the function in a class: in the class constructor, you specify all those values which are part of the parameter list, and you have a special method without arguments to execute the core feature.

something like this:

```
class ContactForm(object):
    def __init__( self, 
                  subj_tmpl='contato/subject.txt',
                  msg_tmpl='contato/msg.html',
                  template='contato/contato.html',  
                  success_template='contato/success.html',
                  success_redir='/',
                  append_message=None):
        self.subj_tmpl = subj_tmpl
        self.msg_tmpl = msg_tmpl
        self.template = template
        self.success_template = success_template
        self.success_redir = success_redir
        self.append_message = append_message

    def __call__( self, request, sender=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL ):
        # do something

# use case:
contact = ContactForm()
contact( req, sndr )
```

*(i guessed which values is site specific and which is user specific from the name of the parameters. i don't know your specific application, adapt it the way you want)*

Comment: another pattern that i recommend not to use. actually, an anti-pattern. you will waste many hours writing boilerplate code like `def __init__( self, a ): self.a = a`. instead, pack everything into a neato dictionary that you can pass around, validate for correctness etc. the above example somehow works because maybe you want in fact produce one contact form and then send it out multiple times. otherwise, it's just OOP gone wrong to me (sorry): isn't this probably a web contact form handler? why do i have to first produce a nonce obj, then call it with more arguments?